# Why this question was closed?

Tags: discussion

[What was the basis for the Nazis to support various ethnic minorities in the Soviet Union and elsewhere over the majority populations?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/5737/what-was-the-reason-for-the-nazis-to-support-various-ethnic-minorities-over-the)

The rationale given reads that this is because none of the perpetrators are currently alive, but is not history a science about ancient times so that participants most of historical events are not alive now?

Answer (score 2):

I left a comment explaining that since the Nazis who were responsible for making these decisions were not available to answer, that means that the rest of us can only speculate on the reasons they had. This further means that any answers provided will be based on opinion or guesses, and furthermore will encourage discussion or debate. All of these are violations of the guidelines for all Stack Exchange sites. Any question that can only be answered with opinion or speculation will be closed.

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
>   format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or
>   specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate,
>   arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this
>   question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for
>   guidance.

Already this question has generated a considerable amount of discussion and even debate. SE is not a discussion forum; it is intended to be a place where people can find clear and concise answers. This question is not worded in a way that will ensure that can happen.

Comment: I am asking about fact, not about opinion. Do you think the only way to determine reasons behind a historical act is to ask the perpetrators?

Comment: How would we know what the facts were if we weren't there? Any question that asks "why" or "how" is almost automatically guaranteed to be closed. "What was the reason" is essentially asking "why"? The rules are the rules; this question is simply not formatted well enough to justify leaving it open.

Comment: "How would we know what the facts were if we weren't there?" - Is not history exist exactly for knowing facts even if not being there?

Comment: "The facts" are things that have been documented and observed which can therefore be reported on. Your question is worded in a way that is asking for people to provide an answer on what someone else's opinions or personal ideas were. If you asked "are there any documented procedures or other evidence that identifies the reasoning behind the Nazis behavior", then that could be answered. It's not "what" you are asking that is the problem, it is "how" you are asking it! That's why the guidelines state that you can try to "improve" the question so it can be reopened!